# Why doesn't the main while loop finish executing? It just hangs up somewhere

Tags: python, class, loops

We are making this Black Jack program to test card counting methods. We are trying to get the auto play function working, and it does, but when we run it in a while loop the loop never finishes and exits.

```
"""
Eli Byers
Josh Rondash

Black_Jack.py
"""
import random

#----------   CLASSES    -----------------------------------------------------------
class Card(object):
    def __init__(self, rank, suit):
        self.rank = rank
        self.suit = suit
        self.value = 0
        if self.rank is "Ace":
            self.value = 11
        if self.rank.isdigit():
            self.value = int(self.rank)
        if self.rank in ["Jack", "Queen", "King"]:
            self.value = 10
    def __str__(self):
        return "["+str(self.rank)+" "+str(self.suit)+"]"

class Deck(object):
    def __init__(self, numofdecks):
        self.deck = []
        self.suit = [" Clubs", " Hearts", " Spades", " Diamonds"]
        self.rank = ["Ace", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "Jack", "Queen", "King"]
        self.numofdecks = numofdecks
        for i in range(self.numofdecks):
            for r in self.rank:
                for s in self.suit:
                    self.deck.append(Card(r,s))  
    def __str__(self):
        deck_str = ""
        for card in self.deck:
            deck_str += str(card)+" "
        deck_str = deck_str[:-1]
        return deck_str
    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.deck)
    def __getitem__(self,i):
        return self.deck[i]
    def __delitem__(self, i):
        del self.deck[i]                           
    def draw(self):
            top_card = self.deck[0]
            del self.deck[0]
            return top_card
    def addcard(self,card):
        self.deck.append(card)
    def shuffle(self):              #Random shuffle function
        a = len(self.deck)
        b = a-1
        for d in range(b,0,-1):
            e = random.randint(0,d)
            if e == d:
                continue
            self.deck[d],self.deck[e] = self.deck[e],self.deck[d]
        return self.deck

class Player(object):
    def __init__(self, bankroll):
        self.hand = []
        self.bankroll = bankroll
        self.score = 0
        self.bet = 0
        self.count = 0
        self.aces = 0
        self.dealer_hand = []
    def __str__(self):
        hand = ""
        for card in self.hand:
            hand += str(card)+" "
        return "Hand: "+hand+"  Bank: "+str(self.bankroll)+"  Bet: "+str(self.bet)+"  Ct: "+str(self.count)+"  A: "+str(self.aces)
    def __getitem__(self, i):
        return self.hand[i]
    def getcard(self,Card):
        self.hand.append(Card)
        self.score = 0
        ace = 0
        for card in self.hand:
            if card.rank == "Ace":
                ace += 1
                self.score += 1
            else:
                self.score += card.value
        for a in range(ace):       
            if (self.score + 10) <= 21:
                self.score += 10
        self.updateCount(Card,"P")
    def placebet(self, b=0):
        if b != 0:
            self.bankroll -= b
            self.bet += b
        else:
            self.bet += input("Bankroll: "+str(self.bankroll)+"  Ct: "+str(self.count)+"  A: "+str(self.aces)+"  Place bet: ")
            self.bankroll -= self.bet
    def updateCount(self, card, player):
        if card.value in range(2,6):
            self.count += 1
        elif card.value is 10:
            self.count -= 1
        elif card.rank is "Ace":
            self.aces += 1
        if player == "D":
            self.dealer_hand.append(card)
    def makeBet(self):
        bet = 0.1*self.bankroll
        if self.count > 3:
            c = 0
            for i in range(self.count):
                c += 1
                if c == 3:
                    bet += 0.5 * bet
                    c = 0
        elif self.count < -3:
            bet -= 0.5 * bet
        return bet
    def Play(self):
        if self.score < 17:
            choice = 1        #hit
        else:
            choice = 2        #stand
        return choice


class Dealer(object):
    def __init__(self, Deck, discardpile, Player):
        self.deck = Deck
        self.discardpile = discardpile
        self.player = Player
        self.hand = []
        self.score = 0
    def __str__(self):
        hand = ""
        for card in self.hand:
            hand += str(card)+" "
        return "Dealer Hand: "+hand
    def __getitem__(self, i):
        return self.deck[i]
    def draw(self):
        cardval = self.deck.draw()
        self.hand.append(cardval)
        self.score = 0
        ace = 0
        for card in self.hand:
            if card.rank == "Ace":
                ace += 1
                self.score += 1
            else:
                self.score += card.value
        for a in range(ace):       
            if (self.score + 10) <= 21:
                self.score += 10
        player.updateCount(cardval,"D")
    def deal(self, Player):
        for i in range(2):
            self.player.getcard(self.deck.draw())
            self.draw()
    def burn(self):
        self.discardpile.addcard(self.deck.draw())
    def blackjack(self):
        if self.score == 21:
            return True
        else:
            return False


class Table(Dealer, Player):
    def __init__(self, Dealer, Player, Deck , discardpile):
        self.dealer = Dealer
        self.player = Player
        self.deck = Deck
        self.discardpile = discardpile
        self.betplaced = 0
    def initGame(self):
        self.clearTable()
        Deck.shuffle(self.deck)
        self.dealer.burn()
    def clearTable(self):
        for card in self.player.hand:
            self.discardpile.addcard(card)
        for card in self.dealer.hand:
            self.discardpile.addcard(card)
        self.player.hand = []
        self.dealer.hand = []      
    def playGame(self):
        self.betplaced = self.player.placebet()
        self.dealer.deal(self.player)
        print self.player
        print self.dealer
        if self.dealer.blackjack():
            print("Dealer Black Jack!")
        elif self.player.score <= 21:
            stand = 0
            while self.player.score < 21 and stand == 0:
                print("Use number Keys> Hit: 1     Stand: 2")
                choice = input()
                if choice == 1:        # Hit
                    self.player.getcard(self.deck.draw())  
                elif choice == 2:     # Stand
                    stand = 1
                print self.player
                print ("Your score is "+str(self.player.score))
            while self.dealer.score <= 17 and self.player.score <= 21:
                if self.dealer.score == 17:
                    for card in self.dealer.hand:
                        if card.rank == "Ace":
                            self.dealer.draw()
                else:
                    self.dealer.draw()
        print self.dealer
        print ("Dealer score is "+str(self.dealer.score))
        if self.dealer.score <= 21:
            if (self.player.score > self.dealer.score) and (self.player.score <= 21) :
                if self.player.score == 21:
                    self.player.bankroll += self.player.bet*2.5
                else:
                    self.player.bankroll += self.player.bet*2
                print ("Win")
            elif self.player.score == self.dealer.score:
                self.player.bankroll += self.player.bet
                print("Push")
            else:
                print("You Lose")
        elif (self.dealer.score > 21) and (self.player.score <= 21):
            if self.player.score == 21:
                self.player.bankroll += self.player.bet*2.5
            else:
                self.player.bankroll += self.player.bet*2
            print ("Win")
        else:
            print("You Lose.")
        self.player.bet = 0
        self.player.dealer_hand = []
        print
    def autoPlay(self):
        self.betplaced = self.player.placebet(int(self.player.makeBet()))
        self.dealer.deal(self.player)
        if (self.dealer.blackjack() == False) and (self.player.score <= 21):
            stand = 0
            while self.player.score < 21 and stand == 0:
                choice = player.Play()
                if choice == 1:        # Hit
                    self.player.getcard(self.deck.draw())  
                elif choice == 2:     # Stand
                    stand = 1
            while self.dealer.score <= 17 and self.player.score <= 21:
                if self.dealer.score == 17:
                    for card in self.dealer.hand:
                        if card.rank == "Ace":
                            self.dealer.draw()
                else:
                    self.dealer.draw()
        if self.dealer.score <= 21:
            if (self.player.score > self.dealer.score) and (self.player.score <= 21):
                if self.player.score == 21:
                    self.player.bankroll += self.player.bet*2.5
                else:
                    self.player.bankroll += self.player.bet*2
                print ("Win")
            elif self.player.score == self.dealer.score:
                self.player.bankroll += self.player.bet
                print("Push")
            else:
                print("Lose")
        elif (self.dealer.score > 21) and (self.player.score <= 21):
            if self.player.score == 21:
                self.player.bankroll += self.player.bet*2.5
            else:
                self.player.bankroll += self.player.bet*2
            print ("Win")
        else:
            print("Lose")
        self.player.bet = 0
        self.player.dealer_hand = []
        print self.player.bankroll


#-----------     MAIN     -----------------------------------

deck = Deck(6)
player = Player(500)
discardpile = Deck(0)
dealer = Dealer(deck, discardpile, player)
table = Table(dealer, player, deck, discardpile)

table.initGame()
while (player.bankroll > 0) and (player.bankroll < 1000):
    table.autoPlay()
    table.clearTable()

print "Game Over."
```

Comment: What debugging have you done? Where do you think the problem might be? Can you reduce this to a [minimal, complete example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? This is too much code to expect others to pore through.

Comment: Python has a function to shuffle a list of values randomly... I think it is in the random module too, and is called random.shuffle(list)... Also, instead of 3 lines to draw a card in the deck class, use just 'return self.deck.pop()' Pop() deletes AND returns the last item in a list.

Comment: I have tried printing out important variables and and testing parts individually but it doesn't always NOT work. Its just when I run the code over and over in a while loop something makes it break. I will try and simplify it but everything is pretty important to making it work. Do you know a good python debugging application?

Comment: If you copy and paste the code into a file and run it you will see that is what i did. I print the bankroll at the end of auto play every time and it it playing and changing the bet. But then it will just stop, the code is still running but nothing is printing and the program counter is not returning. Is there a good python debugger that will show me where the program counter is and lets me set breakpoints and stuff?

Comment: Thanks to everyone who said something and im sorry for the long code this is my first time on Stackoverflow

Answer (score -1):

Just add some debug statements.  You have multiple while loops in your methods.  I'm sure a simple print statement will catch the errors in your logic.

DUDE, I found the infinite loop within 1 minute.  lucky i had python installed on my box.
LINE 251

```
 if (self.dealer.blackjack() == False) and (self.player.score <= 21):
        stand = 0
        while self.player.score < 21 and stand == 0:
            print "in player score"
            choice = player.Play()
            if choice == 1:        # Hit
                self.player.getcard(self.deck.draw())  
            elif choice == 2:     # Stand
                stand = 1
        while self.dealer.score <= 17 and self.player.score <= 21:
            print "in dealer score"
            print self.dealer.score
            if self.dealer.score == 17:
                for card in self.dealer.hand:
                    if card.rank == "Ace":
                        self.dealer.draw()
            else:
                self.dealer.draw()
```

Comment: This does not directly answer the question. It should either be posted as a comment, or deleted.

Comment: @JohnKugelman  IT DOES ANSWER THE QUESTION.  stackoverflow is not for people to debug other people's code.

Comment: Thank you!! I will look for it!